# Servicestack - Order of operation Fluent Validation and Request Filters

Tags: c#, servicestack, fluentvalidation

We have a few request filters and also utilise the validation feature.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true)]
public class MyFilterAttribute : Attribute, IHasRequestFilter
{
   ...
}
```

In AppHost:

```
    public override void Configure(Container container)
    {
        ....
        Plugins.Add(new ValidationFeature());
        ....
    }
```

I need the fluent validation to run after the request filters, as some filters add data to the dto that is then validated. I have seen [Order of Operations](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Order-of-Operations) but that doesn't say where the validation fits in...at least I didn't see.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [ValidationFeature](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/Validation/ValidationFeature.cs) like most things in ServiceStack is just a simple [Plugin](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Plugins) whose source code can easily be found by going to the [ServiceStack GitHub repo](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/) pressing 'T' to activate [GitHub's find files](https://github.com/blog/793-introducing-the-file-finder) feature and start typing in parts of the class name, e.g `VFe` will bring [ValidationFeature](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/Validation/ValidationFeature.cs) up to the first result.

Inside the [ValidationFeature](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/Validation/ValidationFeature.cs) you can see in the `IPlugin.Register(IAppHost)` feature how it works:

```
public void Register(IAppHost appHost)
{
    if(!appHost.RequestFilters.Contains(ValidationFilters.RequestFilter))
        appHost.RequestFilters.Add(ValidationFilters.RequestFilter);
}
```

Which as seen above just registers a [Global Request Filter](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Serialization-deserialization). The [Order of Operations](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Order-of-Operations) points out Global Request Filters are executed after [Filter Attributes](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Filter-attributes) with a Priority `<0` and before Filter Attributes with a Priority `>=0`.

Comment: thanks for answering. I guess the above only applies if the request filter is applied at the Service level, and not method level. Looking at the documentation again method level filter fall under "Action Request Filters (New API only)". Again thanks for answering and your work with SS.

Comment: That seems to exactly be it oczzecho, just noticed the same using the Authenticate attribute on the Actions (instead of at Service level). Authentication was happening after Validation (ugh).